# Re-index row in a SQLite table

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Could anyone help me to show my problem?
I created a table, the below is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" +
                ITEM_INDEX + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                ITEM_ACTIVITY + " TEXT"+
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

ITEM_INDEX and ITEM_ACTIVITY are the declarations for column name of the table.
I inserted data to the table too.
Now, the INTEM_INDEX column are 1,2,3,...
I have a deleteItem function:

```
public int deleteItem(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ITEM_INDEX + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    return result;

}
```

It works fine. But, if I delete the first row, the result is that the table starts with 2,3,4,... for ITEM_INDEX column.
So, what should I do to re-index this column as 1,2,3...?
I'm really grateful for all you helps. 
Thank you!